# PHP: Xml with multiple sibling elements of the same name, maintain order

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, siblings

I have an xml file which looks something like this:

```
<items>
     <itemA/>
     <itemB/>
     <itemA/>
     <itemA/>
     <itemC/>
 </items>
```

but I need to process this using php and maintain the elements order.
I understand how to access the elements with the same name using simplexml and array notation, but I cannot find a way to iterate through them all maintaining their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the parent element and iterate over its children, see http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
'<items>
     <itemA/>
     <itemB/>
     <itemA/>
     <itemA/>
     <itemC/>
 </items>');

foreach ($xml->children() as $item) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the children of `items`; I've added IDs to them to demonstrate that they stay in order.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<items>
     <itemA id="1" />
     <itemB id="2" />
     <itemA id="3" />
     <itemA id="4" />
     <itemC id="5" />
 </items>');

 foreach ($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo "looking at " . $child->getName() . ", id: " . $child['id'] . "\n";
 }
```

Output:

```
looking at itemA, id: 1
looking at itemB, id: 2
looking at itemA, id: 3
looking at itemA, id: 4
looking at itemC, id: 5
```